# Auto redirection in WSO2 API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have an API in WSO2 API manger 1.8 and Production URL with a third  party rest end point.Here the third party rest have 'Location' header with some valid contents.But during the API call the API manger redirecting with some invalid URL (location key conatins in the response of  rest end point and considered  as the URL ) and getting error in wso2 console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed by changing the plugin .This issue already fixed by WSO2 and fix updated in WSO2 ESB ,but fix not updated in WSO2 AM.

This is the JIRA link ,

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3461
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-3818